# Creating dynamic web forms on the client side

Tags: ajax, dynamic, web

Is there an existing library that would do this?

I want to be able to have code on the client side where the user chooses something, it makes a call to the server, and the server sends back "for this option, you need a have a text field called foo and a select field called bar with the following options, this one is selected, etc", and then the client side builds the next part of the form from that information.  Or if they choose a different option, a different set of fields and values is returned from the server and populated on the screen.  Also it might cascade so after the first selection we need a select field with some options, and then depending what they select on that select field the next field might be another select field or it might be a text input field.

Has anybody done anything like that?  Is my best choice to have the AJAX call return some html that I just stuff into a div, or can I do it field by field and value by value?

If it matters, the back end is going to be written in Perl/MASON, and the front end will be using Javascript/JQuery/JQuery-UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery and submit AJAX calls to whatever backend system you choose. Have this backend system compute the necessary changes and return the info as JSON. Let JQuery parse it for you and append the necessary form elements. However, it seems like under alot of use cases these decisions could be made on the client side without even talking to the server just as we pre validate form input before allowing posting to the server. I don't, however, have your requirements in front of me so I am sure there is a reason you want to get the info back from the server.

P.S. please do not return pure html from the back end to the client....ever.